# Techniques to improve the efficiency of Dynamic Time Warping Algorithm

Tags: time-complexity

I am analyzing a set of time series that are shifted along the x-axis (see image below for clarification). I intend to average the time series and for that I would like to overlap all the start points together. The Dynamic Time Warping algorithm is the best algorithm to do the same. However, conventional DTW algorithm seems to be taking a long time to perform the computations. I was wondering if there was a way to accelerate the process.

[image: Overlapping the start points of shapes that are shifted along the x axis]